App-Clip Network Error Code=-1004 with Network Link Conditioner
when trying to connect to our server - I get an error which occurs only in the app-clip:
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server."

more specifically - I get this error when trying to simulate a slow connection with Network Link Conditioner (LTE / 3G).
it only happens on Network Link Conditioner , and only in the app-clip: when I disable the Network Link Conditioner it starts working again.
I receive the error quite fast, so it's not a time-out issue.
things I've tried (and didn't help):

increase time-out period
reduce the network requests to 1 at the time.
set AllowsArbitraryLoads to true

full description of the error:
Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=65, NSUnderlyingError=0x2826aff00 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorNWPathKey=satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0[802.11], ipv4, dns, uses wifi, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=65, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <3D0E9D26-B6BE-41C9-9D97-C61F6E71DBE8>.<3>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <3D0E9D26-B6BE-41C9-9D97-C61F6E71DBE8>.<3>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=<<serverAddress>>, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://<<serverAddress>>, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1})


Did you get anywhere with this? I'm experiencing the same problem, Network Link Conditioner affects the app as expected, but the AppClip is a completely different story:
At first, when using URLSession.shared to create the requests, the Network Link Conditioner didn't affect the AppClip at all. Then, when creating a new URLSession with default configuration for each request, I started to get error code 1004 on all requests as soon as the conditioner was activated.
